# prove $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor \sin\left(x\right)}{x}\right)$ does not exist

Tags: limits

### prove $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor \sin\left(x\right)}{x}\right)$ does not exist

From :

$$-1=\lim _{x\to 0^-}\:\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \sin x}{x}\ne\lim _{x\to 0^+}\:\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \sin x}{x}=0$$

I know that the limit does not exist but I need to prove it with $(\epsilon , \delta)$

Any help how to start with that.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Let there be $L$ a possible limit. We need to find an $\varepsilon$ (the distance of the function from the limit) such that 
$$\forall \delta>0 \exists x\neq 0: -\delta <x<\delta \land |f(x)-L|\geq \varepsilon $$
If $L\neq 0$ we'll choose $\varepsilon = \frac{|L|}{2}$ because then for every delta, if we take $x=min\{ \frac{|L|}{10},\delta ,\frac{1}{2}\}$ we'll see that $-\delta<x<\delta , x\neq 0$ and $f(x)=0  $ meaning $|f(x)-L|=|-L|=|L|\geq \varepsilon$.

So now we agree that if there is a limit, it must be $0$. But it can't be, because we know that
$$\forall \varepsilon \exists \delta \forall x\neq 0 : -\delta<x<\delta \land |\frac{\sin x}{x} - 1| < \varepsilon$$

Now just do some manipulations and it'll get the job done :) .